# How to find the eigenvectors of $(I + A)^{100}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

How to find the eigenvectors of $(I + A)^{100}$
, given $A=\begin{bmatrix}-4 & -5\\10 & 11 \end{bmatrix}$.

I've tried to solve this by the determinant, like this

$det(I+A)=1+|Ai\rm|$, where $Ai\rm$ are all principal submatrices of $A$.

but I can't get more idea about this. If anyone could help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is $A$ a square 2x2 matrix ?

Comment: @5xum thanks to remind me to add my thoughts and ideas. Because I'm a very rookie about this site. I've already edit my question. Thank you for your instruction and advice. If I have anymore idea about this I'll keep on updating my question.

Comment: @Evargalo yes, this is my first time to ask question here, so sorry for my bad typesetting.

Comment: Can you find the eigenvectors of I+A ?

Comment: @Evargalo I figure out how to solve this. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**:

1. If $Ax = \lambda x$, then what is $(A+I)x$ equal to?
2. If $Bx=\lambda x$, then what is $B^2x$ equal to? (remember, $B^2x=B(Bx)$!)
3. From (2), if $Bx=\lambda x$, then what is $B^{100}x$ equal to?

Now, join (1) and (3) together and you should find a simple connection between eigenvectors of $A$ and eigenvectors of $(A+I)^{100}$.

Comment: Oh yhea! I figure out how to solve this.

Comment: How can I figure this by the real world two dimension. If we think this matrix is the linear transformation matrix, when we use the transformation matrix 100 times on a vector to transform. Why the eigenvector is also the same. What the main meaning is?

Comment: @WangWilly The eigenvector is a vector that the transformation simply either stretches or shrinks. If you apply the transformation twice, you just stretched the same vector twice, so of course it still has the same direction...